# Mass Payment Sandbox (IPN) response

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to get MassPay method working with paypal. In specific - to get response on IPN when successful MassPay request has been made.

I am sending NVP request, via curl [as described in the guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/gs_MassPay/). All is working fine as far as request goes (I am receiving errors if authentication is wrong, or format, or paramaters missing)

So after successful submission, I get this as response

```
array (size=5)
  'TIMESTAMP' => string '2014-08-27T05:01:56Z' (length=20)
  'CORRELATIONID' => string '1d9c12a23bd1f' (length=13)
  'ACK' => string 'Success' (length=7)
  'VERSION' => string '90' (length=2)
  'BUILD' => string '12513933' (length=8)
```

So curl  response is ok. However, I am receiving nothing on my IPN listener.

The IPN listener is working fine when I use the IPN simulator (I receive a request). My server logs also shows  POST request to the IPN when using IPN simulator. However nothing when i use API (in sandbox) mode. My server doesn't receive any request from papal at all.

I am using Sandbox account myusername-facilitator@gmail.com , and I've set up IPN url under Profile, Selling tools page.

Both sending and receiving Paypal sanbox accounts funds remain unchanged. Nothing in history as well.

I tried to manually upload MassPayment file (again as one of the options suggested in user guide) on sandbox account. Again, file gets uploaded without errors but that's it. No information on statuses of transactions. No history, nothing.

So, is MassPay working in sandbox mode?? I really need to test my app. IPN simulator doesn't offer a MassPay as option.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I created another business account and that seemed to work. Have no idea why other didn't.